# text to speech how to get call back on UtteranceProgressListener.onRange()

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am trying to get a callback on `onRange()` of text to speech UtteranceProgressListener. Currently I get callback on `onStart()`,`onEnd()`.But I can't get callback on `onRange().`

Can anyone help to get a callback on `onRange()`. Checked sample codes but not able to find a proper solution.

I think I have to use `SynthesisCallback.rangeStart()` but I was unable to get any sample code

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    tv = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    tv.setText("Hello how are you");
    Intent ttsInstallCheck = new Intent();
    ttsInstallCheck.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
    startActivityForResult(ttsInstallCheck, TTS_REQUEST_CODE);

}
@Override
public void onInit(int status) {
    if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

        int result = t1.setLanguage(Locale.US);

        if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
            Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
        } else {
            speakOut();
        }

    } else {
        Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
    }
}

private void speakOut() {
    String text = tv.getText().toString();
    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, text);
    t1.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (TTS_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
        if (TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS == resultCode) {
            t1 = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            t1.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {

                @Override
                public void onStart(final String utteranceId) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, utteranceId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(String utteranceId) {                       
                }

                @Override
                public void onDone(String utteranceId) {                       
                }

                @Override
                public void onRangeStart(String utteranceId, int start, int end, int frame) {
                    super.onRangeStart(utteranceId, start, end, frame);
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + start, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            // not installed
        }
    }
}
}
```